# nodeJS being bombarded with reconnections after restart

Tags: socket.io, nodes, socket.io-1.0

We have a node instance that has about 2500 client socket connections, everything runs fine except occasionally then something happens to the service (restart or failover event in azure), when the node instances comes back up and all socket connections try to reconnect the service comes to a halt and the log just shows repeated socket connect/disconnects.  Even if we stop the service and start it the same thing happens, we currently send out a package to our on premise servers to kill the users chrome sessions then everything works fine as users begin logging in again.  We have the clients currently connecting with 'forceNew' and force web sockets only and not the default long polling than upgrade.  Any one ever see this or have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your socket.io client code, you can force the reconnects to be spread out in time more.  The two configuration variables that appear to be most relevant here are:

**reconnectionDelay**

Determines how long socket.io will initially wait before attempting a reconnect (it should back off from there if the server is down awhile).  You can increase this to make it less likely they are all trying to reconnect at the same time.

**randomizationFactor**

This is a number between 0 and 1.0 and defaults to 0.5.  It determines how much the above delay is randomly modified to try to make client reconnects be more random and not all at the same time.  You can increase this value to increase the randomness of the reconnect timing.

See [client doc here](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) for more details.

---

You may also want to explore your server configuration to see if it is as scalable as possible with moderate numbers of incoming socket requests.  While nobody expects a server to be able to handle 2500 simultaneous connections all at once, the server should be able to queue up these connection requests and serve them as it gets time without immediately failing any incoming connection that can't immediately be handled.  There is a desirable middle ground of some number of connections held in a queue (usually controllable by server-side TCP configuration parameters) and then when the queue gets too large connections are failed immediately and then socket.io should back-off and try again a little later.  Adjusting the above variables will tell it to wait longer before retrying.

---

Also, I'm curious why you are using `forceNew`.  That does not seem like it would help you.  Forcing webSockets only (no initial polling) is a good thing.

Comment: We implemented the forceNew just recently as an attempt to resolve this.  This was a suggestion from Microsoft  as we had a case open with them regarding this because our node service is hosted in Azure.   I will try your suggestion for sure.

Comment: We made a change to reconnectionAttempts so the client will stop reconnecting after 5 attempts.  The issue happened after we implemented this but it never resolved the issue.  Yesterday we changed the reconnectionAttempts to 2.  I know Azure uses IIS and iisnode not sure if that may play a factor or not.